# Typescript function parameter has two types, and the property of one type can't be accessed because it is not a property of the other type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component:

```
<GoogleLogin
  clientId={googleAppId}
  onSuccess={responseGoogle}
  onFailure={responseGoogle}
  isSignedIn={true}
  cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
  autoLoad={false}
  icon={true}
/>
```

And the following function for its `onSuccess` and `onFailure` props:

```
const responseGoogle = (
  response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline
) => {
  console.log(response.accessToken);
};
```

I only want to use the type `response: GoogleLoginResponse`, but if I do so, I get the following error from the library:

```
Type '(response: GoogleLoginResponse) => void' is not assignable to type '(response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => void'
```

So I'm using `response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline` as the parameter.

The problem is that when I try to access the property `accessToken` of the type `GoogleLoginResponse`, I get the following error, because `accessToken` is not a property of `GoogleLoginResponseOffline`:

```
Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline'.
  Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'GoogleLoginResponseOffline'.
```

How can I access to the property `accessToken` of `response`?

Notes:

- I'm using the following React library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login.
- I do not use `response: any` because it is not considered a good practice.
- `GoogleLoginResponse` and `GoogleLoginResponseOffline` types definition: https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/blob/master/index.d.ts.

Comment: "I only want to use the type ..." — why? What if it isn't that one? Do you somehow _know_ that this can't happen?

Comment: The documentation indicates that you can either use the `accessType="online"` or `accessType="offline"` prop (the default is "online") for the `GoogleLogin` component. Since I'm using the `accessType="online"`, the response will be of type `GoogleLoginResponse`. For more details: https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login#onsuccess-callback--w-offline-false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you can use [type guards](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard) to narrow down the type by using type guards.

```
const responseGoogle = (
  response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline ): void => {
    if ('accessToken' in response ){ 
        console.log(response.accessToken);
    }else {
        console.log('offline'); 
    }
}

responseGoogle({accessToken:'abc', name: 'Jim'})
responseGoogle({name: 'Joan'})
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said you should use only `response: GoogleLoginResponse` but it will throw the error you mentioned

```
Type '(response: GoogleLoginResponse) => void' is not assignable to type '(response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => void'
```

so you could try editing `index.d.ts` file in `node_modules\react-google-login\index.d.ts` (or ctr+click on the error) and edit line 75 deleting `| GoogleLoginResponseOffline`

Reslut:

`readonly onSuccess?: (response: GoogleLoginResponse) => void`

save and refresh you may need to restart the app.